# Further simplify an 'API' that's async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

So let's say I have this code:

```
function DBManager()
{
    this.getContactsList = function(cb)
    {
        $.post('/post/getContactsList', function (contacts) {
            cb(contacts);
        });
    }
}
```

Then this:

```
var DBManager = new DBManager();

DBManager.getContactsList(function (contacts) {
    console.log(contacts);
});
```

I actually have a lot more functions inside DBManager, and the above code with the callbacks seems redundant so I was wondering if there would be more optimal ways to make calls to DBManager?

Comment: Well... `$.post` already returns a promise so the callback is redundant, you can do `return $.post(...)` and then do `DBMnaager.getContactsList.then(...`

Answer (score 2):

You could use promises in JavaScript to accomplish the same functionality provided by callbacks. If you are using RSVP.js or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
function DBManager()
{
    this.getContactsList = function()
    {
        return $.post('/post/getContactsList');
    }
}

var DBManager = new DBManager();

DBManager.getContactsList().then(function (contacts) {
    console.log(contacts);
});
```